# Can we use variable class names to declare variables in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Something like

```
Class tableViewCellClass = BGUIBusinessCellForDisplay.class;
tableViewCellClass * cell = (tableViewCellClass *)tableView.visibleCells[0];
```

That gets compile error.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're confusing two separate stages of your progam: compilation time and run time. The variable's type only exists during the first stage. The return value of `[BGUIBusinessCellForDisplay class]`, which is an object, doesn't exist until later, at run time. However, there is almost certainly a way to accomplish your goal, so please explain what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot type it using the class variable - as it's an object, not a type. You can however type it `id`. e.g.

```
Class myClassVar = self.class;
id newInstance = [[myClassVar alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

Typedefs are as close as you can get:

```
typedef BGUIBusinessCellForDisplay tableViewCellClass;
```

Which somewhat allows you to do what you want, but the overall question I have is what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: typedef is at compile time. I tried to have a code that will work with 2 types of UItableViewCells. The codes are similar but I want one subclass to deal with one type and the other with another type.